# Sometimes I am unable to submit my question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, posting

While submitting the question in stack overflow and while submitting the form I got this issue:

[image]

Comment: Please include basic debugging information like browser & OS and reproduction steps. It would be great if you could also press F12 and look for any errors in the console.

Comment: related: [AJAX issue piling up activity indicators on each click of a deleted question review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300049/ajax-issue-piling-up-activity-indicators-on-each-click-of-a-deleted-question-rev). Which makes me believe that you've been hammering the button.